# Navigation bar and text moves when viewed on different computers or resized

Tags: html, css

I am new to this. On my website, when the window is resized or is viewed on a different computer screen, the navigation bar (which is made up of rectangles and triangles) and text moves around and parts disappear. Do the sizes need to be in percentages? If so I am unsure of which parts I need to change.

To view it, please follow this link [to my website on Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/jadewnc/codebits/rtKQff) and click on the full screen button.

```css
body {
    background-image:  url('http://www.rgbstock.com/cache1u7YbL/users/x/xy/xymonau/300/nXWyMYC.jpg')
}

#background {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30%;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 90px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.photocontainer {
    border: transparent;
    height: 55%;
    width: 65%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.photocontainer img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.navcontainer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 10%;
    width: 99%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.navcontainer .navbar .navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
}

.navcontainer .navbar .navigation li a {
    font-family: quicksand;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    width: 110%;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 31px;      
}

.navigation li a:hover {
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.navbar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 42px;
}

.navcontainer .navbar .rectangle {
    background: #f1e5cd;
    height: 62px;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 500; /* the stack order: foreground */
    margin: 3em 0;
}

.navcontainer .navbar .l-triangle-top {
    border-color: #e7dbc3 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 1px;
    left: -50px;
}
 
.navcontainer .navbar .l-triangle-bottom {
    border-color: transparent transparent #e7dbc3;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: -40px;
    left: -150px;
    }

.navcontainer .navbar .r-triangle-top {
    border-color: #e7dbc3 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: -45px;
    top: -107px;
}
 
.navcontainer .navbar .r-triangle-bottom {
    border-color: transparent transparent #e7dbc3;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: -149px;
    right: -145px;
}
```

```html
   <div id="background">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div class="navcontainer">
     <div class="navbar">
     <!-- the left side of the fork effect -->
       <div class="l-triangle-top"></div>
       <div class="l-triangle-bottom"></div>
     <!-- the ribbon body -->
       <div class="rectangle">
         <!-- the navigation links -->
         <ul class="navigation">
           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Order</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
    <!-- end the ribbon body -->
    </div>
 
    <!-- the right side of the fork effect -->
         <div class="r-triangle-top"></div>
         <div class="r-triangle-bottom"></div>
 
    <!-- end container -->
    </div>
 </div>

    <div class="photocontainer"></div>
```

Comment: What is `width: 110%;` on your anchors supposed to achieve? Please add either as a runnable code snippet or even better, as a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @connexo It was in px, but I changed the width to a percentage because the container was appearing as different sizes on different computers. I have linked the website, but I've also put it into jsfiddle.net as you asked.
http://jsfiddle.net/L74gdm7j/

Apologies, I am very new to all of this and I am still learning

Comment: The problem comes from the way you position your triangles. You need absolute positioning from those, otherwise they affect the position of your navigation list.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article "http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp"
Your code is a bit confused.
Hope this helps.

Here you have a basic example:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that .triangle divs ... are affecting the positioning of the content of div .rectangle
I would try these absolutely positioned and then accommodate the div .rectangle

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution in my fiddle, including absolutely positioned triangles. For simplification purposes I removed your header.

http://jsfiddle.net/L74gdm7j/2/

```css
body {
    background-image: url('http://www.rgbstock.com/cache1u7YbL/users/x/xy/xymonau/300/nXWyMYC.jpg')
}
#background {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.photocontainer {
    border: transparent;
    height: 55%;
    width: 65%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.photocontainer img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.navcontainer {
    height: 10%;
    width: 99%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navcontainer .navbar .navigation {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navcontainer .navbar .navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.navcontainer .navbar .navigation li a {
    font-family: quicksand;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 31px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
.navbar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 42px;
}
.navcontainer .navbar .rectangle {
    background: #f1e5cd;
    height: 62px;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 500;
    /* the stack order: foreground */
    margin: 3em 0;
}
.navcontainer .navbar .l-triangle-top {
    border-color: #e7dbc3 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -38px;
}
.navcontainer .navbar .l-triangle-bottom {
    border-color: transparent transparent #e7dbc3;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -38px;
    left: -38px;
}
.navcontainer .navbar .r-triangle-top {
    border-color: #e7dbc3 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -38px;
    top: 0;
}
.navcontainer .navbar .r-triangle-bottom {
    border-color: transparent transparent #e7dbc3;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -38px;
    right: -38px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div class="navcontainer">
            <div class="navbar">
                <!-- the left side of the fork effect -->
                <div class="l-triangle-top"></div>
                <div class="l-triangle-bottom"></div>
                <!-- the ribbon body -->
                <div class="rectangle">
                    <!-- the navigation links -->
                    <ul class="navigation">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Order</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end the ribbon body -->
                </div>
                <!-- the right side of the fork effect -->
                <div class="r-triangle-top"></div>
                <div class="r-triangle-bottom"></div>
                <!-- end container -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="photocontainer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: & in general: Stop constantly using relative positioning and pushing the elements left and right and up and down. You do this only in special, rare cases, but never as a standard procedure. You get yourself into unsolvable positioning problems even with such simple markup otherwise.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tips. I'm a little confused with you're solution though... if you shrink the window, the text moves off of the navigation bar and the edge of the triangles get cut off. Is there a way to stop this?